# Creating customs controls in Android

Tags: android, controls, custom-controls

I want to create my own custom controls in Android application and use them in this way:
In the XML file:

```
<MyButton .... />
```

I would like to define MyButton some where in the resources XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own subclass of `View` (e.g., `com.ofirbit.MyButton`) and then reference it in your layouts (e.g., `<com.ofirbit.MyButton android:id="..." />`). [Here is an Android library project and demonstration sub-project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) showing an implementation of a custom `ColorMixer` widget and its use in an application. The details of how to implement one of these can be found in [some Android books](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid), the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), and perhaps elsewhere.